# Finding sub string in a string using Regex.Match

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find following sub string out of my string. String which I want to find is as follow

```
<Canvas Canvas.Left="450" Canvas.Top="343.54" Width="202.5" Height="75" Background="#00FFFFFF">
    <:RubberBand x:Name="RubberBand1" Canvas.ZIndex="-1" LineStroke="{Binding Path=LineColor, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=AdvancedValueBox1}" StrokeThickness="{Binding Path=LineThickness, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=AdvancedValueBox1}" ShowLine="{Binding Path=ShowLine, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=AdvancedValueBox1}" TargetAnchorPosition="Center" ValueAnchorPosition="LeftCenter" X1="52.5" X2="72.5" Y1="32.5" Y2="32.5" TargetId="07d572f9-2e94-4f26-bdb7-489897c92f7d" ValueId="0d4ef226-f6c5-43f0-b4fc-c3bc6a04d16d">
      <:RubberBand.TargetPropertyMappings>
        <s:String>PrimaryValueBindingProperty</s:String>
        <s:String>LabelBindingProperty</s:String>
        <s:String>AlarmBindingProperty</s:String>
        <s:String>SecondaryValueBindingProperty</s:String>
      </jcge:RubberBand.TargetPropertyMappings>
      <jcge:RubberBand.ValuePropertyMappings>
        <s:String>PrimaryValueBindingProperty</s:String>
        <s:String>LabelBindingProperty</s:String>
        <s:String>AlarmBindingProperty</s:String>
        <s:String>SecondaryValueBindingProperty</s:String>
      </:RubberBand.ValuePropertyMappings>
    </:RubberBand>
    <:TemperatureMap x:Name="Room_Status1" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" PrimaryValueBinding="metasys-value:Object Reference 1,813" Label="adPatch" AlarmBinding="metasys-item:Alarm extension 1" NavigateTo="metasys-item:Navigation Path 1?aliasString=Aliasing String 1"
   >
      <:TemperatureMap.Data>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,75,75" />
      </:TemperatureMap.Data>
    </:TemperatureMap>
    <:AdvancedValueBoxAnchor x:Name="Advanced_Value_Box1" Canvas.Left="42.5" Canvas.Top="22.5" jcge:RubberBand.ID="07d572f9-2e94-4f26-bdb7-489897c92f7d" AlarmBinding="metasys-item:Alarm%20-%20Present%20Value" PrimaryValueBinding="metasys-value:" />
    <:AdvancedValueBox x:Name="AdvancedValueBox1" Canvas.Left="72.5" Canvas.Top="20" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11" PrimaryValueBinding="{Binding Path=PrimaryValueBinding, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=Advanced_Value_Box1}" SecondaryValueBinding="{Binding Path=SecondaryValueBinding, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=Advanced_Value_Box1}" AlarmBinding="{Binding Path=AlarmBinding, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=Advanced_Value_Box1}" LabelBinding="{Binding Path=LabelBinding, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=Advanced_Value_Box1}" jcge:RubberBand.ID="0d4ef226-f6c5-43f0-b4fc-c3bc6a04d16d" />
  </Canvas>
```

using Regex how can I do That I want to use following string in my pattern. It must contain   following strings `<Canvas`, `<jcge:TemperatureMap`,`<jcge:AdvancedValueBoxAnchor` and closing tag of `</Canvas>`

Answer (score 0):

You *should* probably use an XML parser for this task (eg [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387063%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) on the assumption that this is not a 'one off' quick parse out, and you might not always be able to guarantee that your input (xml) is formatted in the same way.

**Edit**
If you give an example of what XML you would like as a result I'll happily put a quick sample piece of code together.